# Why isn't acts-as-taggable-on adding tags to posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

Just set everything in acts-as-taggable-on but now it's not adding tags to posts.
Here's the post model

```
acts_as_taggable_on :tags
```

in th user model

```
acts_as_tagger
```

in the posts controller

```
def permit_post
params.require(:post).permit(:image, :title, :long, :anonymous, :facenumber, :hidden, :granted, :tag_list => []);
end
```

.

```
puts @tags
#=>ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = ? AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = ? AND "taggings"."context" = ?  [["taggable_id", 26], ["taggable_type", "Post"], ["context", "tags"]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = ? AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = ? AND "taggings"."context" = ?  [["taggable_id", 26], ["taggable_type", "Post"], ["context", "tags"]]
puts @post.tag_list 
#=> 'tag1, tag2,tags'
```

in the routes

```
resources :tags, only: [:index, :show]
```

and when I add a tag I get

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "taggings".* FROM "taggings" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = ? AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = ?  [["taggable_id", 28], ["taggable_type", "Post"]
```

Comment: post your output from your console when you try to tag something.

Comment: @bkunzi01 added the logs